# Let $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$. Find distinct functions $f:A\to A$ and $g:A\to A$ such that $g\circ f\neq f\circ g$.

Tags: functions, solution-verification

This question appeared in my text book while solving. I am not super sure about the solution to it. Can anyone please check my solution? I can't consult my professor right not (by mail) because it's midnight here.

I am unable to attach a picture of my work but my answer is:
$$f:\{(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 1)\}, and\\
g:\{(2,1),(1,3),(3,3)\}$$
It will be very helpful  if you tell me whether it is correct or not.

Comment: It is correct but you should say why $g\circ f \neq f\circ g$. You can mention that $g(f(2))=1\neq 2=f(g(2))$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is correct. Another solution would be to take $f$ and $g$ to be constant functions $1$ and $2$. Then
$$f\circ g=f\ne g=g\circ f$$